# In wordpress how do i add a sidebar to a single[post-type].php

Tags: wordpress

I was like trying everything but i cant solve my problem.

I created a single-mainpage-news.php, it show the sidebar but doesnt show the links.

```
<?php
            $has_subpages = false;
            $children = wp_list_pages('&child_of='.$post->ID.'&echo=0');
            if($children) {
                $has_subpages = true;
            }
            $children = "";

            if(is_category() && $post->post_parent) {

                $children .= wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->post_parent ."&echo=0");
            } else if($has_subpages) {

                $children .= wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->ID ."&echo=0");
            }
            ?>
            <?php if ($children) { ?>
            <?php echo $children; ?>
            <?php } ?>
```

and it uses a main page category

could please someone help?

Comment: You may want to re-write the title of this question, I am sure you would obtain more answers, right now it has little to do with your problem (if I understood it correctly that is).

Answer (score 0):

Could just be that your page is neither a parent page (`$has_subpages`) nor a category archive (`is_category()`) or a children (`$post->post_parent`)?

Note that having an AND in your conditional implies that to be true the page has to be at the same time a category archive AND a children page. Do you really have this type of page? Do you perhaps just want to check for a children page?

Also, note that a page can be a parent and children at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for your tips, i mannaged to do it, i feel really silly, the problem was that its a single page and i didnt used is_single.